# Eclipse doesn't see classes from Maven modules in workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

We have some Maven modules shared between several teams, with the mandate to share the source code even though our projects use different dependencies and resources. To accomplish this, we have our modules set up as recommended in [Using Maven When You Can't Use the Conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html) under "Producing Multiple Unique JARs from a Single Source Directory." Specifically, we have a shared parent module containing the src directory but whose pom declares `<packaging>pom</packaging>` and only builds the two submodules. Each submodule inherits from this parent and refers to the shared src directory using this:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>../src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

The two submodules have different artifact ids, allowing dependent modules and projects to specify which version and dependency set they need. It also upholds the Maven principle of "one module, one output."

This all works great in Maven-land: compilation, installation, deployments, etc. What doesn't work well is Eclipse integration. Some things work fine: building the modules, deploying to our Maven repo, pulling in dependencies to build our project. But things such as code completion and jumping to class/method definitions do not work at all. It's as though Eclipse doesn't recognize the source at all.

If we just check out a module from SVN, Eclipse doesn't know about the classes but instead uses jars from the repo. If we then import the modules as Maven modules, they show up in package explorer and the project build path. However, all references to those classes and methods are now flagged as errors by Eclipse. And we still do not have code completion or navigation.

So my questions are these: How can we get Eclipse to recognize the code and do its normal code navigation while still satisfying our varying project requirements? Am I missing some simple Eclipse configuration? Do we need to rework our Maven module structure, and if so, how?

Some additional context: The different dependencies for the projects are rather large, including different major versions for things such as Weblogic and Spring. The Weblogic versions will converge some time next year, but the other dependencies will be slower (and some resource files will likely always remain distinct). So for the near- to mid-future, we have to account for different dependencies between the projects.

We are using profiles to allow our Jenkins server to build both submodules while allowing individual developers to build only the submodule their project needs. Using profiles to manage the dependencies is problematic because we lose transitivity of dependencies.

**Update** (12/8/15)

I was eventually able to make Eclipse recognize the source directory by using "Link Source..." on the "Configure Build Path..." dialog. Adding a source folder would not let me reference the module's parent directory, but Link Source let me assign an arbitrary directory to use. It's not ideal, but it seems to be working.

Comment: I'm guessing you also read this part: "The Maven developers highly recommend you use this as a **last resort**". I'm guessing that M2Eclipse has trouble with such a project structure. Besides updating it to the latest version, I don't think there anything you can do, except, of course, going back to the sane default project structure.

Comment: Yes, this was used as a last resort, with the hope that the drawbacks would be tolerable. Is there a way to use the default structure given the different dependencies? I considered separate pom files making separate artifacts, but my understanding is that Eclipse would only pay attention to pom.xml; one of the projects would be left out in the cold.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea... I fear you are going to feel alone on this one.

Comment: If you like to share code do it on the jar level which means simply use dependencies. Maven is based on the idea of sharing dependencies and not on sharing source code...mandate to share source code does not make sense and has no advantage etc. in contradiction it has disadvantages...If you like to use the tools like Eclipse you should follow the conventions in Maven...

Comment: Given that we have modules that need to be built for separate environments (Weblogic 10 and 12), including EJBs that must be compiled and packaged for the right app server, I was hoping for an interim solution until our environments converge. The only convention the current structure seems to violate is that the src directory is one level up from the usual, and Maven seems happy to use it. Only Eclipse is uncooperative. I would hope there is a way to manage these separate build environments such that both Maven and Eclipse would be heppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to make Eclipse recognize the source directory by using "Link Source..." on the "Configure Build Path..." dialog. Adding a source folder would not let me reference the module's parent directory, which derailed me for a while. However,Link Source let me assign an arbitrary directory to use.

It's not ideal, but it seems to be working. We can now jump to definitions with F3, and errors are now highlighted correctly. It's good enough that I don't feel bad recommending it to the other team. I wish Eclipse would automatically allow a parent source directory to be referenced, but at least the manual intervention worked right.